# ¿Cómo hago para que al hacer click en la flecha correspondiente (der/izq) el visualizador cambie de imagen, con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que al clickear en la flecha correspondiente (der/izq) el visualizador cambie de imagen... Lo quiero hacer en JavaScript. Estoy aprendiendo programación... Ahí va mi código (éste hasta ahora sólo me amplía la imagen seleccionada para visualizarla):

```
const hamburguer1 = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const imagenes = document.querySelectorAll(".img-galeria");
const imagenesLight = document.querySelector(".agregar-imagen");
const contenedorLight = document.querySelector(".imagen-light");


const aparecerImagen = (imagen)=>{
      imagenesLight.src = imagen;
      contenedorLight.classList.toggle("show");
      imagenesLight.classList.toggle("showImage");
}

imagenes.forEach(imagen =>{
      imagen.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
      aparecerImagen(imagen.getAttribute("src"));
      })
})

contenedorLight.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    if(e.target !== imagenesLight) {
        contenedorLight.classList.toggle("show");
        imagenesLight.classList.toggle("showImage");
    } 
})

imagenes.forEach(img =>{
      flecha.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        aparecerImagen(images[img]);
    })
})
```

La Section involucrada del código es:

```
<section class="gallery" id="actualidad">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <h2 class="subtitulo">Galería</h2>
            <div class="contenedor-galeria">
                <img src="uno.jpg" alt="" class="img-galeria" id="img1">
                <img src="dos.jpg" alt="" class="img-galeria" id="img2">
                <img src="tres.jpg" alt="" class="img-galeria" id="img3">
                <img src="cuatro.jpg" alt="" class="img-galeria" id="img4">
                <img src="cinco.jpg" alt="" class="img-galeria" id="img5">
                <img src="seis.jpg" alt="" class="img-galeria" id="img6">
            </div>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="imagen-light">
        <img src="comment-x-regular-24.png" alt="" class="close">
        <img src="flecha-hacia-izquierda.png" alt="" class="flecha"> /* Flecha hacia la 
izquierda */ 
        <img src="" alt="" class="agregar-imagen"> 
        <img src="flecha-hacia-derecha.png" alt="" class="flecha"> /* esta sería la flecha 
hacia la derecha */ 
    </section>
```

Me gustaría saber qué función puedo crear para que al clickear las flechitas me cambie de imagen. Son seis imágenes en total. Los estilos de css de las clases intervinientes son:

```
.flecha {
    width: 60px;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.gallery {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

.contenedor-galeria {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-galeria {
    width: 30%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.imagen-light {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translate(100%);
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.show {
    transform: translate(0);
}
.agregar-imagen {
    width: 60%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform .3s .2s;
}

.showImage {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Al código lo fui generando a partir de un video de YouTube donde te enseñan a crear una página web con html, css & JavaScript. Pero no muestra esa partecita importante en la visualización de las imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero le pones un identificados a las flechas: id="flechaDer" (avanzar, ir a la derecha) y id="flechaIzq" (retroceder, ir a la izquierda).
Crearía una función para determinar el índice de la imagen actual.
A cada flecha le pondría un evento para que pase a la imagen isguietne o anterior a la actual.

```
//Busca el indice de la imagen que se está mostrando en este momento
function imgActual()
   {
     var actual = imagenesLight;
     for(i=0; i<imagenes.length; i++){
        if(imagenesLight.src === imagenes[i].src)
            break;
        }
    if(i=== imagenes.length) i=0;    //si no hay imagen mostrándose
         return i    
   }

document.getElementById('flechaIzq').addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        let actual = imgActual();  
        if( actual >0) actual--;
        aparecerImagen(imagenes[actual].src);
        })
document.getElementById('flechaDer').addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        let actual = imgActual();  
        if (actual < imagenes.length-1) actual++
             aparecerImagen(imagenes[actual].src);
        })
```

Es prácticamente un carrusel.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo que noto es que este método que me pasaste sólo me deja cambiar una sola vez de imagen. Igualmente me sirvió mucho de guía!

Comment: De nada. Y si puedes mover desde la imagen mostrada hacia adelante o atrás, más de una vez. Míralo en [aquí funcionando](https://javascript.espaciolatino.com/muestras/visor.htm)

Comment: A mi no me estaría funcionando; te paso la página que tiene la galería a ver si podes ver mi error... https://piliansa.github.io/riouruguay/

Comment: Has quitado el break del bucle de buscar actual.  Si lo quitas i siempre vas a recorrer todo la lista de imágenes. Lo he puesto para que no recorra toda la lista, pues cuando encuentra la imagen actual ese valor de i es el índice de la que está mostrándose.

Comment: perdón lo había comentado para probar otra cosa. Sigue sin funcionar, ahí cargué el break.

Comment: Curiosamente se emueve entre lamimg 1 y 2. Miraré, es extraño.

Comment: Claro es que también tienes un ;  **(punto y coma)** justo al final de la línea del **if  antes del  break**, con lo que  corta el bucle con i=0. Quita ese punto y como.

Comment: Si, ahí lo quité y sigue pasando.

Comment: Compara el código de la solución con el de la página y verás que en la función imgActual  el bucle tien mal la condición ahora mismo tienes  for(i=0; i<imagenesLight  y es i< imagenes.length. Esta función busca en todas las imágenes cual es la que se está mostrando.